# how to convert kivy project into apk for android

Tags: python, kivy, apk

I have a project that contains a `.py` file and `.kv` file and .txt file and I want to convert all that to a `.apk` file, is it possible to do that using Google Colab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Solution

You can actually do it on Google Colab

Press cancel to the popup to open a new notebook

Initialize the VM by pressing *Connect* in the top-right part of the page

Then add a new *Code Cell* by pressing *+Code*

To set up buildozer and other commands, paste into the cell and press the play icon

```sh
!pip install buildozer
!pip install cython==0.29.19
!apt install -y \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
!apt install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
!apt install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6
!apt install libffi-dev
!pip install kivy
!apt install ldd
```

Then upload your files to the files page

Make another cell and run `!buildozer init`

Refresh the files screen by right-clicking and going to refresh

Open and edit the `buildozer.spec` file as you wish

**NOTE**: You may need to edit the `.spec` file to include the .txt and .kv files.

I'm guessing the edited line should look something like this `source.include_exts = py,kv,txt`

Finally, make a new cell and run `!buildozer -v android debug` and wait for it to complete, *you may need to accept a few licenses on the way*

When done, refresh the file page again and then navigate to the bin directory that should now appear, press on the three dots of your apk, and press download

Comment: I tried it with a project and it worked but with another one it gived an error

Comment: What was the error and what do you mean with a project

Comment: thank you so much I solved the error i just froget to include th .txt file